# HTTP GET のパラメーターをスラッシュで渡す方法

Tags: php, nginx

getのURLのパラメーターをスラッシュで渡すにはどのような設定をすれば宜しいでしょうか。
www.example.com/?id=1
上記を下記のようにしたいと考えています。
www.example.com/id/1
言語はphpでserverはnginxを使っています。

詳しい方、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

nginxにてrewriteの設定定義を行えば解決すると思います。

例)

```
rewrite  ^/(.*)/(.*)$    /?$1=$2    last;
```

(実際に動かしたわけではありません)

https://yhmwss.yhm.kyocera.co.jp/android/default.aspx

PHP側は以下で動作しているのであれば特に変更する必要はありません。
www.example.com/?id=1