# サイトの構造について

Tags: php, html

https://nanapi.jp/123443
上記のサイトの構造はどうなっているのでしょうか。
IDを名前にしたファイルをIDの数だけ生成しているのでしょうか？
例）上記であれば123443.phpといった風に
それとも、別の方法で上記のようなURLを実現しているのでしょうか。
詳しい方、ご教示下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: nanapi 自体は現在Railsになっているようです。 (参考:[nanapiをRailsにする際にやってよかったこと、やらなかったこと](http://blog.nanapi.co.jp/tech/2015/01/30/nanapi_on_rails/))

Rails であれば routes で `/path/:id` みたいに指定して、URLのパスよりパラメーターを取得できます。

となりますと、本件のタグから推測するに、質問は「PHPで同じことをやるにはどうしたら良いか」ということになりますが、それで良いでしょうか? 仮にそうでなければ、Railsの解説にならざるを得ません。

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。PHPでどのように実現するのかを知りたいと思っております。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP GET のパラメーターをスラッシュで渡す方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16440/)
みたいに URL の一部を変換することで `?` を使う URL パラメータに変換してるんでしょう。
パラメータ変数の値からデータベースにアクセスすればよくなるので、ファイルにする必要はなくなります。

nanapi.jp が本当にそういう実装であるかは知りません。